# Implementing MySQL / PHP to chartjs

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, chart.js

I've seen couple problems regarding this matter, and none of the "solved" has helped me so far.

Here is my current code. I've tried to change and tweak the implementation of MySQL/PHP, but with no luck. Any help is appreciated in advance!

Original controllers.js

```
function MainCtrl($http){
this.barData = {
    labels: ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        },
        {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(26,179,148,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(26,179,148,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(26,179,148,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(26,179,148,1)",
            data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
        }
    ]

  };
};
```

my current controllers.js (not working)

```
function MainCtrl($http){

$(document).ready(function(){
         var charDataSql = '';
     $.ajax({
         url: 'http://localhost/js/chart_data.php',
         type: 'GET',
         success: function(data) {
             charDataSql = data;
this.barData = {
    labels: charDataSql,
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        },
        {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(26,179,148,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(26,179,148,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(26,179,148,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(26,179,148,1)",
            data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
        }
    ]

  };
      }   
  });
  });
};
```

chart_data.php output is json_encode

```
["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"]
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The way your question is written it is not clear to me.

Comment: @AlexanderJardim Basically bringing month from php file that is connect to mysql. and after i accomplish that i will try to import more data from mysql.